# HyperSQL: Drop Table in Stored Procedure

Tags: database, hsqldb

I am new to HyperSQL (migrating from SQL Server to in-memory dbms for performance purposes), so please forgive me if this is a syntactical issue. When I try to execute the following query in the Database Manager, it throws an error: "Unexpected token: DROP"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bspTable_CleanUp(ProcesslogID INT, AlgorithmID INT)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC

    DROP TABLE GlobalVariable IF EXISTS;
    ...
END;
```

Is it not possible to drop tables from inside stored procedures in HSQL? Or this something I shouldn't even try to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of HSQLDB (2.3.2) does not allow any DDL statements in stored procedures. This may be allowed in future versions.

Comment: Thank you fredt, do you know if there is a forum where you can request these sort of features?